# How the Sun orbits

Tags: astrophysics, orbital-motion

So the Sun is a population I star, right? Then why does it's orbit form a rosette shape, characteristic of pop II stars?

source:

w.astro.berkeley.edu/~echiang/classmech/gd2_chapter3.pdf page 166. this is from binney & tremain, Galactic dynamics

p166

Comment: Source for the Sun's orbit being a rosette?

Comment: @probably_someone 


w.astro.berkeley.edu/~echiang/classmech/gd2_chapter3.pdf page 166. this is from binney & tremain, Galactic dynamics

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Every star's orbit forms a rosette. It's just a consequence of the orbits not closing, which is purely a consequence of the particular form of the galactic gravitational potential. The Sun's orbit is pretty nearly circular; Pop II stars have more elliptical orbits, so the rosette shape is more obvious.